# Is it safe to load from QUiLoader without all the boiler plate in python?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm an amateur experimenting with python gui development (python 3, PySide2, QtDesigner). My code works fine, I'd just like to understand something a little better.

All the tutorials load the ui like this (in the constructor):

```
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
...
# in the constructor
    loader = QUiLoader()
    file = QFile(self.__resource('the_ui_file.ui'))
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    self.ui = loader.load(file, None)
    file.close()
```

However, this works just as well:

```
self.ui = QUiLoader().load('the_ui_file.ui')
```

Given python's garbage collection, is the shorter version safe to use? Are there any drawbacks to this approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no problem since the GC will remove it after it finishes its scope that is after loading the widget.

The only disadvantage is that you will only load a single widget, but if you have an instance of QUiLoader you can load several widgets from other .ui. Maybe you see it a lot because it goes in [the docs of PySide2](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html#detailed-description), and this is based on the [docs of Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html#details)  that does not have a version similar to the short version.